# How to get 'All Upright' ribbon for Food Fight level 15 (Melony Offense)?

Tags: achievements, ios, bag-it

In *Bag It* I have one more ribbon to get - for 'All Upright' on Food Fight level 15. Unfortunately the only source of solutions I've seen ([this YouTube user](http://www.youtube.com/user/IPHONEIGAMEPLAYS)) does not have the solution for this level.

The items are:

- 2x melon
- 2x milk
- 2x egg box
- 3x breadstick
- 1x OJ
- 1x cereal
- 1x banana (J shape)

And the melons must not touch. Here is one combo with some elements sideways:

[image: Bag It]

I've tried all manner of combinations and have not managed it with the items all upright. I'm sure the trick is in some combination of the banana and breadstick. Has anyone completed this level with the ribbon?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

Took me a while to get it, hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks! By the way if you're still having problems with level 14, ask a separate question and I'll answer it :)